# Magento Custom Payment Gateway

Tags: magento, payment

I'm trying to write a custom payment gateway for Magento.  The module is recognised in the administration backend (System - Config - Payment Methods), but when reaching 'Payment Information' in the frontend, the option to select the module does not appear.

Below contains the three XML files I have created, and the directory in which they reside.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

**root/app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**root/app/code/local//Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>

  <global>

    <models>
        <alias>
            <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
        </alias>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <alias_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Namespace_Module</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </alias_setup>

         <alias_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </alias_write>

        <alias_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </alias_read>
    </resources>

  </global>
```

**root/app/code/local//Namespace/Module/etc/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <sections>
    <payment>
        <groups>
            <alias translate="label">
                <label>Module</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                <fields>

                    <active translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled: </label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </active>

                    <title translate="label">
                        <label>Title: </label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </title>

                    <host translate="label">
                        <label>Host Address: </label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </host>

                    <port translate="label">
                        <label>Port Number: </label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </port>

                    <cctypes translate="label">
                        <label>Credit Card Types: </label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_cctype</source_model>
                        <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </cctypes>

                    <useccv translate="label">
                        <label>Credit Card Verification: </label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </useccv>

                </fields>
            </alias>
        </groups>
    </payment>
</sections>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values you setup in `system.xml` are global Magento configuration values.  Payment module's are required to include a configuration field named `model`, which specifies the PHP class that's responsible for payment logic.   Take a look in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml
```

Typically, a module makes this a hidden configuration field, and then supplies a default value in `config.xml`. Consider this bit of XML from  `Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml`

```
<default>
    <payment>
        <ccsave>
            <active>1</active>
            <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI</cctypes>
            <model>payment/method_ccsave</model>
            <order_status>pending</order_status>
            <title>Credit Card (saved)</title>
            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            <group>offline</group>
        </ccsave>
```

Here they've setup a model of `payment/method_ccsave`.  This is a class alias that corresponds to the PHP Model class

```
Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Ccsave
```

You configuration appears to be missing this class, which is one reason your payment option doesn't appear.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have added in a model class and linked to it accordgingly; still nothing, however.

If anybody can notice anything else that may be missing, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no .xml extension on the file in app/etc/modules/ in your example above.  Magento is looking for a *.xml file in this folder before it will load any of your module's XML files.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml doesn't seem to have a "blocks" section defined.  So I assume you do not yet have the *.phtml file created either.  I experienced the same problem.

The example found here helped me:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/230559/

Take note of the "blocks" section of the config.xml.
Also, notice the Blocks/*.php file and the form.phtml file.