# Magento get guest and logged in customers name, email and order number/reference number at checkout page

Tags: email, magento, checkout, mage

I am trying to get the customer's name, email, and order number to pass to a payment gateway once the customer hits the place order button. So far I have managed to get the total using

```
$total = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

I tried using

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

$email = $customer->getEmail();  

$firstname = $customer->getFirstname(); 

$lastname= $customer->getLastname();
```

but they don't seem to return a value. I know this because I echo the variables after, and none of them work but the $total. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you should use some query to fetch the last order by current user after the order button hit , because i think the order number is generated after gets the entry in database or you can use the query on success page where you can get the order number also

Comment: thanks for the response but I need it the details before I get to the success page, to post it to the payment gateway

Comment: than i think you can place the query on that same page right after the button hits ,
 right now which value is submitting to gateway at the time of hit ?

Comment: dont worry I found a better solution look at this link:

http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/#comment-1429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a Custom Payment Gateway module.

See

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method

[Magento Custom Payment Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237317/magento-custom-payment-gateway)

http://roysimkes.net/blog/2009/11/creating-your-own-payment-gateway-for-magento-part-1/

http://roysimkes.net/blog/2009/11/creating-your-own-payment-gateway-for-magento-%E2%80%93-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for your response that exactly what I did using this tutorial and files:

http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/#comment-1429